# Does purchasing something in Subway Surfer remove pop-up ads?

Tags: in-app-purchase

Pop-up ads in *Subway Surfer* annoy me a lot. Can I get rid of them by purchasing something like Double Coin feature? I am unable to find any information about it on their official website. If you have ever purchased something in it, please share your experience. Does it remove pop-up ads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you're talking about *pop up ads*.

If you're talking about the full screen ad, often for another game, that pop up when you go to the main menu for example, then no, I don't get any ad since I have purchased the double coin bonus.

If you're talking about the push notifications that warn you about daily challenge and new events, purchasing something doesn't remove it, but you can turn them off in the settings (`Reminders`).